# Set password to a backup file in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

Is there a method to set a password to a backup file of SQL Server 2008 R2 ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this please, I believe it is no longer suported in `SQL Server 2012` so I cannot verify.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Sandbox] TO  DISK = N'f:\..\Sandbox.bak' 
WITH PASSWORD = 'StackOverflow'
```

**The protection provided by this password is weak. It is intended to prevent an incorrect restore using SQL Server tools by authorized or unauthorized users. It does not prevent the reading of the backup data by other means or the replacement of the password. The best practice for protecting backups is to store backup tapes in a secure location or back up to disk files that are protected by adequate access control lists (ACLs). The ACLs should be set on the directory root under which backups are created.**

[BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: This feature is [indeed deprecated in SQL Server 2012 (first on the list)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) and should **not** be used anymore

Comment: @marc_s - Thanks :) What I meant is that I cannot verify the syntax because I am running 2012. I worded it poorly.

Comment: Your syntax is fine! :-) Verified on SQL Server 2008 R2 (Developer)